# python "with" command and csv reader

Tags: python, csv

I have both csv readers and writers. I understand you have to open and close the underlying object. One way to do it it would be to first create the file object, f, use csv reader and then use f.close().

However, I can't seem to do the following:

```
with open(outputpath) as f_outputfile:

    outputfile = csv.writer(f_outputfile)

OTHER CODE HERE
```

What I want to do is open a bunch of readers at once and a bunch of writers at once and have them all close automatically. However, does that mean I have a nested "With" block?

Comment: Does `OTHER CODE HERE` use `f_outputfile`?

Comment: More appropriately, is `OTHER CODE HERE` the part that writes to the csv file?

Comment: Yes, it does. Say I want 3 readers and 2 writers and they all need each other. Other CODE HERE writes the CSV file.

Comment: Then you should make `OTHER CODE HERE` part of the with block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing:

```
with open(outputpath) as f_outputfile:
    outputfile = csv.writer(f_outputfile)

OTHER CODE HERE
```

Is essentially the same as:

```
f_outputfile = open(outputpath)
try:
    outputfile = csv.writer(f_outputfile)
finally:
    f_outputfile.close() 

OTHER CODE HERE
```

If `OTHER CODE HERE` relies on the file being open, it's not going to work.

Comment: It's only essentially the same if csv.writer can't throw exceptions (which is never true in python).

Answer (score 3):

You can stack multiple items in the [with statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-15) as in (looks like this is a 2.7.x and higher feature):

```
with open(foo) as f_foo, open(bar) as f_bar:
    # do something
```

> 7.5. The with statement
>
> New in version 2.5.
>
> The with statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with
>   methods defined by a context manager (see section With Statement
>   Context Managers). This allows common try...except...finally usage
>   patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.

```
with_stmt ::=  "with" with_item ("," with_item)* ":" suite
with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
```

Comment: This throws an error, not sure why then:

with open(outputpath,"w") as f_outputfile, open(inputpath, "r") as f_inputpath:

Comment: Just verified it works in 2.7.3, what version are you using?  Just took a peek at the 2.6 docs and there it only allows single with_item's this is probably a 3.x feature back-ported to 2.7.x

Comment: I'm using 2.6.6, that must be why. It's ok, I can do nested "withs". Just to make sure, I don't need to worry about close commands now yes? They will now close automatically?